# JavaScript. How to control background image slide show to synchronize with bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create backgroundImage slide show with bubbles. i was working very fine untill i added eventListeners for mouseover and mouseout.
mouseover enent clears the setInterval while the mouseout calls back the setInterval(). 
The execution is triggered with the setInterval in the window load event.
i dont know if my explained my problem very well

```js
var bubble_Array;
var bubble_i = 0;
var intrval;
var ba;
var bi =0;
var intr;


var man = ['url(imags/ParLour.jpg', 'url(imags/767.jpg', 'url(imags/7series.jpg', 'url(imags/02.jpg', 'url(imags/BedRoom.jpg', 'url(imags/30.jpg', 'url(imags/volks.jpg', 'url(imags/sports.jpg', 'url(imags/real.jpg', 'url(imags/portable.jpg', 'url(imags/perspective.jpg', 'url(imags/green.jpg', 'url(imags/fantom.jpg', 'url(imags/fantom2.jpg', 'url(imags/elegance.jpg', 'url(imags/bridge.jpg', 'url(imags/BMW.jpg', 'url(imags/interior.jpg','url(imags/3Dcar007.jpg'];


function _(x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}

function bubbleMain(bi){
 bubble_i++;
 if(bubble_i == man.length){
  bubble_i = 0;
 }
 _('bubblebox').style.opacity = 0;
 for (var i =0; i < ba.length; i ++){
  ba[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,.1)";
 }
 
 setTimeout(function(){
  _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
  ba[bi].style.background = "red";
  _("bubblebox").style.opacity = 1;
 }, 500);
}
function bubbleSlide(){

 ba = _('bubbles').children;
 _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
 ba[bi].style.backgroundColor = 'red';


 bi++;
 if (bi == ba.length){
  bi =0;
 }
bubbleMain(bi);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 ba = _('bubbles').children;
 _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
 ba[bi].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  intrval = setInterval(bubbleSlide, 2000);
 })

window.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
 clearInterval(intrval);
})

window.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
 intrval = setInterval(bubbleSlide, 2000);
})
```

```css
#bubblebox{
height: 550px;
width: 1200px;
border:2px solid black;
margin: 50px auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: -5;
background-size: cover;
transition:background-image 0.2s;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#bubbles{
 height: 0px;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;

}
#bubbles div{
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 border: 2px solid green;
 border-radius: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px auto;
 top: 10px;
 z-index: 1000;
 left: 310px;
 color:#fff;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#heading{
 height: 20px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
 left: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#arrow_right, #arrow_left, #arrow_middle{
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 transition: .5s;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: -4px 4px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
 cursor: pointer;
 left: 1100px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 -10px 0 0px;
 top: 200px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#arrow_right2, #arrow_left2, #arrow_middle2{
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 transition: .5s;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: -4px 4px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
 cursor: pointer;
 left: 10px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 -10px 0 0px;
 top: 200px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 tex
}

#arrow_right2:hover, #arrow_left2:hover, #arrow_middle2:hover{
box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#arrow_right:hover, #arrow_left:hover, #arrow_middle:hover{
box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div id="bubblebox">
 <div id="bubbles">
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(0)">1</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(1)">2</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(2)">3</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(3)">4</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(4)">5</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(5)">6</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(6)">7</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(7)">8</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(8)">9</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(9)">10</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(10)">11</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(11)">12</div>
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(12)">13</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(13)">14</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(14)">15</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(15)">16</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(16)">17</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(17)">18</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(18)">19</div> 
  <div onclick="bubbleMain(19)">20</div>
 </div>
 <div id="heading">Caption</div>
<div id="arrow_right"></div>
<div id="arrow_middle"></div>
<div id="arrow_left"></div>

<div id="arrow_right2"></div>
<div id="arrow_middle2"></div>
<div id="arrow_left2"></div>
 <div id="bubblecontent"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a perfect one , still check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/qck9ocja/)

Comment: @Durga, thanks you. It is working now. This is really helpful thank you. Am new to javascript  and web development.